# Train and predict on a varying number of inputs - time based events

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection

I have the problem where I am trying to build a model which takes in `n` events for a single user as input for prediction, the problem is that the number of events is not set, so for example:

A user may have performed a single event:
time - eventType - eventData

Yet another user for whom I need a prediction may have performed many of these time based events.

What architectures / models can I explore?

Comment: The events are independent or do you have a dependent sequence?

Comment: They are web events - page views, so independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with sequence data it is usual to have sequences with different sizes. One answer for your problem might be to using **padding** in your events, in this way you keep a fixed number of events for all your data.

It happens in the same way with NLP applications, let's set number of events to be **five.**

So you have the following two rows in your data set:

```
UserID | time     | eventType | eventData
1        08:00:00      A           X
1        08:01:00      A           X
1        08:02:00      B           X
1        08:03:00      C           Y
1        08:03:00      A           Z
1        08:00:00      A           X
2        07:00:00      A           Z
2        07:01:00      B           X
```

So, you have for userId = 1 six events and for userId = 2 two events. Using paddings = 5, you will add 'Null'/Zero data for user 2 and you will truncate one event for user 1. Usually, you keep the last ones, so your data will become:

```
UserID | time     | eventType | eventData
1        08:01:00      A           X
1        08:02:00      B           X
1        08:03:00      C           Y
1        08:03:00      A           Z
1        08:00:00      A           X
2        07:00:00      Null        Null
2        07:00:00      Null        Null
2        07:00:00      Null        Null
2        07:00:00      A           Z
2        07:01:00      B           X
```

But what about the null values? You can use GradientBoosting algorithms that deals with null values by default. Or a missing imputation stretegy such as the most common value or a new class indicating null value.

Then, to finish, you can transform your data to have each user a row in your dataset:

[image]

Notice that your 'window' size is a hyperparameter and it is a good practice to define it via cross-validation.

I hope it helps.